# Can one galaxy have a higher dark matter ratio than another?

Tags: gravity, universe, dark-matter, galaxies

Dark matter do not interact with ordinary matter and light, it has mass and is affected by gravity. If the distribution of dark matter and ordinary matter is evenly spread at the early universe then I suppose the ratio should remain the same in every galaxy right? Or is there any mechanism for more dark matter to gather in some galaxies?

Comment: See "https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00095"

Comment: See this https://www.sissa.it/sites/default/files/PR%20SISSA_New%20Clues%20on%20Dark%20Matter.pdf . It seems that all galaxies behave the same

Comment: @CinaedSimson: That paper doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question. It's a proposal for explaining rotation curves without dark matter.

Comment: This might be better for astronomy.SE. A possibly relevant paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05052 The impression I get is that people talk about things like universal rotation curves https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Battaner/node7.html , but these are generalizations, and there is actually considerable individual variation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, absolutely. It's well known that the dark matter (DM) fraction varies from galaxy to galaxy, usually as a function of the galaxy (stellar or baryonic) mass. In general, the dark matter fraction is lowest for massive galaxies like our own Milky Way, and increases for both higher-mass galaxies (which are rare) and for lower-mass galaxies (which are common).

In addition, there have been recent claims that a few "ultra-diffuse" dwarf galaxies [have very little dark matter](http://www.sci-news.com/astronomy/second-galaxy-no-dark-matter-07114.html), and that a few more gas-rich ultra-diffuse dwarfs [may also mostly lack dark matter](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019NatAs.tmp..493G/abstract) (see also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01363)) So there is some evidence for large variations in the dark-matter fraction of dwarf galaxies, even though on average they tend to have higher dark-matter fractions than galaxies like the Milky Way.

There are generally two factors to consider: the first is how much dissipation the baryonic matter undergoes, which allows it to concentrate in the center of the galaxy (DM cannot undergo dissipation). The second is whether significant amounts of baryonic matter can be ejected from a galaxy due to star formation (strong stellar winds from massive stars, supernova explosions) and/or the action of an active galactic nucleus (e.g., jets from the accretion disk around a central supermassive black hole); these factors won't affect the DM except very indirectly (that is, if significant gas flows out of a galaxy, its gravity will pull somewhat on the DM).

Other possibilities include the effects of interactions, including tidal stripping of both dark matter and gas, [ram-pressure stripping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_pressure) (which removes gas but *not* dark matter), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some galaxies seem to have very little" dark matter". Also nobody knows for sure if dark matter is some exotic extraordinary matter(it isnt almost certainly) . It's just that most galaxies spin faster that their gravity alone can hold together. And some don't so they don't necessarily require an assumption of some strange matter.

Comment: *Also nobody knows for sure if dark matter is some exotic extraordinary matter(it isnt almost certainly) .* If you want to argue against the scientific consensus on dark matter, that's fine, but it makes this not a useful answer to the actual question.

Comment: Also, it's definitely not "_just that most galaxies spin faster that their gravity alone can hold together_". There is much more observational evidence, e.g. velocity dispersion in clusters, gravitational lensing, CMB measurements, baryonic acoustic oscillations, etc., all yielding roughly the same amount of dark matter.

Comment: @ pela All Those could be caused by a number of things, to say it's just some dark matter is just lazy, unscientific and right out of star wars or something. "Roughly the same" you can stretch that but you'll still have a serious mismatch, grav cosmology is falling apart.

Comment: @ben did you answer? I clarified what DM means really, it means the shortcoming of grav cosmology to account mostly for the spin of galaxies among other things, conveniently blaming it on the incompleteness of particle physics

Comment: @BenCrowell " If you want to argue against the scientific consensus on dark matter" - How the answer goes against scientific consensus. Every one knows dark matter is a hypothesis. All the attempts to detect it, have not given any positive results to date, so, what is wrong with "it isnt almost certainly"? And when did science start to be based upon consensus? The reasoning/claim in the answer appears to me based upon truth as it stands today.

Comment: @kpv I could not have said it any better.