# Questions about Dark Matter and Galactic Rotation

Tags: dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

First, does the dark matter halo and galactic rotation of a galaxy depend on it's size? So bigger galaxies, bigger dark matter halo.

Secondly, is the amount of dark matter for a galaxy universal? So every galaxy has a precise amount as opposed to visible matter and if so, how precise is this value.

Comment: When you say *"galactic rotation"* do you mean collective angular momentum of that galaxy. Also, in the second part of your question do you mean does the amount of dark matter correspond to the amount of other matter?

Comment: @Pagoda Yes, that galactic rotation. Also, yes as to how dark matter corresponds to the amount of visible matter.

Comment: For the second: No; see my answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/520537/can-one-galaxy-have-a-higher-dark-matter-ratio-than-another